# why numpy.in1d() works more faster in my example but my object?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

The 2 tables I have to deal with  in my object like this:

TABLE1:

| code_material | yield |
| --- | --- |
| 1000100001 | 1000 |
| 1000100002 | 500 |
| 1000100003 | 1024 |

where code_material is a ten-digit number whose value does not exceed 4e+9

TABLE2:

| code_material_manufacturing | input/output | code_material | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000100001 | 1000154210 | IN | 100 |
| 1000100001 | 1123484257 | IN | 100 |
| 1000100001 | 1000100001 | OUT | 50 |

What I want to do is get code_material from table 1 and then search the first column of table 2 to find its index.
And for some values of 'code_material' in TABLE1 and 'input/output' in TABLE2 may have the character '-' be included, like'-1000100001', indicating that they are half-finished products.

I use `str` as the dtypes for both cols, and `np.in1d()` to do like this:

```
# read data from excel
TABLE1 = pd.read_excel(path1, 
                       dtype={'code_material':str, 'yield':float})
TABLE2 = pd.read_excel(path2,
                       dtype={'code_material':str, 'input/output':str,
                              'code_material':str, 'qty':float}

# convert to numpy array
_output = TABLE1['code_material'].to_numpy()
output = _output[~np.char.count(_output, '-')!=0]  # To remove half-finished

table2 = TABLE2.to_numpy()

# some operations to help me find those outputs, not casts.
_idx_notproduction = np.argwhere(table2[:, 2]=='IN')
idx_notproduction = np.argwhere(np.in1d(output, table2[_idx_notproduction, 1]))

# operating segment
j = 0
output = output.tolist()

while j < len(output):
  production = output[j]
  idx_in_table2 = np.argwhere(table2[:, 0] == production)
  # find those input casts
  idx_input = idx_in_table2[:-1]  # Sliced to prevent production from counting itself in.
  input = table2[idx_input, 1][~np.char.count(table2[idx_input, 1], '-')!=0]
  
  idx = np.inid(input, table2[:, 0])  #  here's the in1d that confuses me.
```

It takes about 0.00423s each time.

But when I tried a similar instance, I found that `np.in1d()` ran almost one order of magnitude faster than I had in the object (about 0.000563s each time). Here is my example:

```py
arr1 = np.random.randint(1, 3e+9, (1, 5), dtype=np.int64)     # average of 5 codes per search
arr2 = np.random.randint(1, 3e+9, (1, 1170), dtype=np.int64)  # len(TABLE2)=1170 in object
arr1, arr2 = arr1.astype(str), arr2.astype(str)
cost = 0
for i in a:
  s = time.perf_counter()  #For the purpose of timing
  idx = np.in1d(arr1, arr2)
  cost += time.perf_counter() - s

print(cost/len(a))
```

I would like to ask what causes such a big difference in speed between the two `in1d()`? Is it possible to use this cause to optimize my code in the object to this speed?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use `str`? The values in `code_material` look like they are numerical

Comment: To prevent some material code starting with 0.(But the fact that I've never seen it, so if you can offer advice with int, feel free to)

Comment: Looks like the slower case is a pandas dataframe, and most likely you are testing Series with object dtype.  `in1d` is best for numpy arrays with numeric dtype, though the `str` dtype is ok - check `arr1.dtype`.

Comment: no, in fact I use np.array for both cols in my object, so it's confused me

Comment: What is the precise type of `TABLE2`? What is its stride if it is a Numpy array? What are the types of the columns if it is a Pandas dataframe? Such parameters are critical for performance and are not provided. It would strongly help us to understand the problem if we could reproduce it. If I understand your question correctly, you give an example of fast code which is good but no example for the slow code which is the problematic one. Note `a` does not exist in the provided code. Please provide *reproducible* examples (for the two use-case you are comparing).

Comment: thx for suggestion , and I edit an example of my code now

Comment: Thank you, this is better, but the two codes are still not reproducible because `a` is undefined, nor `path1` and `path2` (and we do not have the file even though you give an example of them).

Comment: The problem is certainly that `TABLE2.to_numpy()` results in a Numpy arrays containing pure-Python objets. Such objects are very inefficient (both time and memory space). You need to select 1 specific column and then convert it to a Numpy array. The operation you use will only be reasonably fast if all the dataframe columns are of the same type. Besides, note that comparing string is expensive as indicated by hpaulj. To compare "1000100001" with another string, Numpy will compare each of the 10 character using a basic loop while comparing an integer with another take only about 1 instruction.

Comment: Besides, note that Pandas always stores strings in pure-Python objets. AFAIK, Numpy needs to update the reference counting for each objet and care about locking/releasing the GIL, not to mention memory indirections are required and strings are generally stored using Unicode which tends to be often more expensive (such to additional checks). All of this is far much expensive than comparing integers. Please reconsider the need to use strings. You can use a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) if needed (eg. negative integers) and even map them to a set of predefined strings.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion of 'np.to numpy'. As soon as I get back to the lab tomorrow, I will try the method you suggested. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thx again and it‘’s work, please put your answer in "ANSWEAR" so I can set your reply as the best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer build from previously posted comments as requested by the OP:

The problem is certainly that `TABLE2.to_numpy()` results in a Numpy arrays containing pure-Python objets. Such objects are very inefficient (both time and memory space). You need to select 1 specific column and then convert it to a Numpy array. The operation you use will only be reasonably fast if all the dataframe columns are of the same type. Besides, note that comparing string is expensive as indicated by @hpaulj. To compare "1000100001" with another string, Numpy will compare each of the 10 character using a basic loop while comparing an integer with another take only about 1 instruction.

Besides, note that Pandas always stores strings in pure-Python objets. AFAIK, Numpy needs to update the reference counting for each object and care about locking/releasing the GIL, not to mention memory indirections are required and strings are generally stored using Unicode which tends to be often more expensive (such to additional checks). All of this is far much expensive than comparing integers. Please reconsider the need to use strings. You can use a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) if needed (eg. negative integers) and even map them to a set of predefined strings.

Last but not least, note that Pandas supports a type called [`category`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html). It is usually significantly faster than plain strings when the number of unique strings is significantly smaller than the number of rows.